# Join fetch múltiplo retornando valores duplicados JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, spring, join, criteria

No método em questão estou querendo retornar a consulta com os joins de empregado e empresa. Porém, a classe Empresa está relacionada com a Consulta e com o Empregado, e está retornando duplicada no JSON.

Classe Consulta

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONSULTA")
public class Consulta implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id;

@Column(name="IDEMPRESA")
private Long idEmpresa;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="IDEMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "ID", 
insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Empresa empresa;

@Column(name="IDEMPREGADO")
private Long idEmpregado;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="IDEMPRESA", referencedColumnName="EMPRESA", insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="IDEMPREGADO", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
})
private Empregado empregado;

/* Getters e Setter */
}
```

Classe Empresa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPRESAS")
public class Empresa implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name="CIDADE")
private Long idCidade;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CIDADE", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Cidade cidade;

@Column(name="RAZAOSOCIAL")
private String razaoSocial;

private String denominacao;

private String cnpj;

private String ddd;

private String fone;

private Character status;

private Long usuario;

/* Getters e Setter */
}
```

Classe Empregado

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPREGADOS")
public class Empregado implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private EmpregadoPK id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Empresa empresa;

private String nome;

/* Getters e Setters */

}
```

Método com os fetch

```
public Consulta getById(Long id) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Consulta> cq = cb.createQuery(Consulta.class);
    Root<Consulta> consulta = cq.from(Consulta.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    predicates.add(cb.equal(consulta.<Long>get("id"), id));

    cq.distinct(true);

    consulta.fetch("empresa");
    consulta.fetch("empregado");

    cq.select(consulta).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

    TypedQuery<Consulta> tquery = em.createQuery(cq);
    tquery.setMaxResults(1);

    return tquery.getSingleResult();
}
```

JSON de retorno

```
{
"id": 1268,
"data": "2018-03-27",
"hora": "01/01/1970 09:00:00",
"descricao": null,
"idEmpresa": 1,
"empresa": {
    "id": 1,
    "razaoSocial": "Demonstração LTDA"
},
"idEmpregado": 45,
"empregado": {
    "id": {
        "idEmpresa": 1,
        "id": 45
    },
    "empresa": {
        "id": 1,
        "razaoSocial": "Demonstração LTDA"
    },
    "nome": " ANA MARIA COSTA PORTO",
    "admissao": "2017-09-13",
    "demissao": null,
    "nascimento": "1966-11-17",
    "sexo": "M",
    "matricula": "65989898"
},
"status": "1"
}
```

Comment: Inclua o JSON que está sendo retornado, afim de facilitar o entendimento do cenário.

Comment: @WeslleyTavares editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O caminho mais simples para evitar a repetição da informação relativa a entidade `Empresa` (uma vez que eu desconheço o seu modelo de dados) seria utilizar o recurso `@JsonIgnoreProperties` na classe `Empregado`, incluindo o atributo `empresa`, conforme ilustrado a seguir:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "empresa" })
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPREGADOS")
public class Empregado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmpregadoPK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Empresa empresa;

    private String nome;

    /* Getters e Setters */

}
```

É possível fazer uso do mecanismo de ignorar um atributo de uma classe quando for sofrer *serialization* para JSON de outras formas (usando o `@JsonIgnore`, por exemplo), porém prefiro utilizar desta forma que foi utilizada no exemplo por questões de facilidade na leitura do código e também para futuras inclusões e/ou remoções de atributos para o JSON.

Agora uma dúvida acerca do seu modelo de dados: qual o motivador da classe `Consulta` se relacionar tanto com `Empregado` quanto com `Empresa`? Observe que somente o relacionamento com a classe `Empregado` seria o suficiente para se obter todas as informações constantes no seu JSON.